# Reading in a File with a Pattern in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, parsing

I am trying to parse a file that has a person's name and address and then some transactions that have been completed on their account. The data is in an old text file, where there is a header for the person's name and address and then some empty lines and a header with transactions headings ("   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE"), followed by a line " ----------------------------------------------------------------------- " an empty line and then the set of transactions. After a certain number of lines, the file will reproduce the name and address of the persons on the account and another header with transaction information followed by more transactions. Just trying to figure out a way to parse the file so I end up with just the account number in one column and all transactions information (Date, Description, Deposit, Withdrawal, Balance) in other separate columns.

The file looks kind of like this:

```
ABC COMPANY                                                     
JAN 01 2020 TO OCT 30 2020                                                      
000000001                                                                      
                      ABC COMPANY                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
      JOHN SMITH                                                          
      1590 STEWART CRES                                                         
      NOWHERE AB                                                                 
      Z9T 6Y9                                                                   
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                  ACC: 000000001              PAGE:    1        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 04 CHQ PLAN 24                        242.76        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   .64                         243.40        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   .04                         243.44        
 MAR 16 20 DEBIT MEMO                              10.00-         233.44        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              .00          233.44        
 AUG 05 20 TRANSFER                 40.00                         273.44        
 AUG 05 20 FROM ACC # 12345                                                     
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 05 SHARES                              40.00        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              .00           40.00        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 07 PREMIUM SAVINGS                  1,720.64        
 JAN 31 20 INTEREST                  2.19                       1,722.83        
 FEB 29 20 INTEREST                  2.05                       1,724.88        
 MAR 31 20 INTEREST                  2.20                       1,727.08        
 APR 30 20 INTEREST                  2.13                       1,729.21        
 MAY 31 20 INTEREST                  2.20                       1,731.41        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              .00        1,731.41        
 JUN 30 20 INTEREST                  2.14                       1,733.55        
 JUL 31 20 INTEREST                  1.59                       1,735.14        
 AUG 31 20 INTEREST                  1.55                       1,736.69        
 SEP 30 20 INTEREST                  1.50                       1,738.19        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 16 EURO CASH SAVINGS                  100.07        
 JAN 31 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.08        
 FEB 29 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.09        
 MAR 31 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.10        
 APR 30 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.11        
 MAY 31 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.12        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              .00          100.12        
 JUN 30 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.13        
 JUL 31 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.14        
 AUG 31 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.15        
 SEP 30 20 INTEREST                   .01                         100.16        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 17 U.S. SAVINGS                          .00        
000000001                                                                      
                      ABC COMPANY                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
      JOHN SMITH                                                          
      1590 STEWART CRES                                                         
      NOWHERE AB                                                                 
      Z9T 6Y9                                                                   
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                  ACC: 000000001              PAGE:    2        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              .00             .00        
000000053                                                                      
                      ABC COMPANY                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
      JACKIE SMITH                                                              
      MARTHA MAGEE                                                 
      28 HALL CRT                                                           
      NOWHERE AB                                                                 
      Z9T 6Y9                                                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                  ACC: 000000053              PAGE:    1        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 04 CHQ PLAN 63                      6,196.04        
 JAN 02 20 EFT WITHDRAWL                          111.89-       6,084.15        
 JAN 02 20 ABC GAS                                                         
 JAN 04 20 CHEQUE           CK#     66             75.00-       6,009.15        
 JAN 07 20 EFT WITHDRAWL                           62.32-       5,946.83        
 JAN 07 20 NOWHERE HYDRO                                                        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                 29.49                       5,976.32        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   .77                       5,977.09        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   .71                       5,977.80        
 JAN 31 20 INTEREST                   .02                       5,977.82        
       
000000053
```

I have done some work in Python and this is what I have so far:

```
import re

N = 17 #2416065
num_members = 0
with open('sample.txt', "r") as file:
    for i in range(N):
        line = next(file).strip()
        if line == "DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE" :
            line = next(file).strip() # Skip "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
            line = next(file).strip() # Skip empty line
            line = next(file).strip() # Read a real transaction
            print(line.split())
            line = next(file).strip()
            print(line)
            print(re.findall(r"[-+]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)",line))
            i = N + 1
```

I am trying to parse one of the transaction lines and not sure how best to go about it. The transaction line formats are a bit tricky for me in that in some cases there are dollar amounts there and some cases not. In some cases there is only 2 dollar amounts (i.e. deposit and balance) and I guess the only way to know whether it's a deposit or a withdrawal is by the position. In the text file, deposits end at column 42, for withdrawals they end at column 57 and for balances they end at column 73. There are no tabs in between the amounts only spaces. In the code I have so far I am trying to parse:

```
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   .64                         243.40
```

And it's coming out like:

```
 ['31', '19', '.63', '222.76']
```

using print(re.findall(r"[-+]?(?:\d*.\d+|\d+)",line)). The trouble with this method is I can't tell if the '.63' is a deposit or withdrawal with this method and I am wondering if there is a way I can somehow specify the ending positions for deposits, withdrawals and balances to better parse this and get rid of the date numbers '31', '19'?

This is the first snag I have run into and I am listing the whole sample file in hopes that someone may be able to help with parsing the transaction as well as any tips on parsing the file in general.

Unfortunately, I am quite new to Python so I am afraid I may be going the wrong way about this and perhaps there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: *For some reason the "----------------------------------------------------------------------- " lines are showing up as a solid line in my question and the transaction headings are showing up in bold.* This is because markdown recognizes --- as the symbol for a line and # as a header symbol. You can use the code styling to prevent this, which I did in my edit.

Comment: Is it one person per file or multiple accounts in one file?

Comment: @dawg there are multiple accounts in one file. And in the cases where an account spans "a page" the account info(name and address) is repeated (like in the case of John Smith) and then other transactions are listed.

Comment: Is there a page break prior to a new account in the file? FF or page break would be hex `0xC`...

Comment: @dawg I think there is one just before the account number gets reprinted, there is an   up arrow symbol that is printed just before the account number. In sample I gave, the first page ends after  "JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 17 U.S. SAVINGS                         .00"        
And then the account number "000000001" is printed and just before that account number there is an up arrow which I think is a FF but I can't tell - I don't have Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Your data especially your `DESCRIPTION` consists of dynamic values which I think the 1st challenge while manipulating the data. In my opinion, the second challenge here is to identify if the values in the middle of each line belongs to `DEPOSIT` or `WITHDRAWAL`. To resolve the 2nd issue, if it is possible to influence your data as adding `*` in the beginning of your `DEPOSIT` values and `#` in the beginning of your `WITHDRAWAL` values, it helps to identify which values belongs to which of them, as most of your line includes only one of them. If it is possible solve 2nd problem as such, the 2nd challenge would also be resolved with the recommendation of using python ttp module to parse your data. Please see the following code:

```
from ttp import ttp
import json

data_to_parse = """
ABC COMPANY                                                     
JAN 01 2020 TO OCT 30 2020                                                      
000000001                                                                      
                      ABC COMPANY                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
      JOHN SMITH                                                          
      1590 STEWART CRES                                                         
      NOWHERE AB                                                                 
      Z9T 6Y9                                                                   
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                  ACC: 000000001              PAGE:    1        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 04 CHQ PLAN *24                        242.76        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   *.64                         243.40        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   *.04                         243.44        
 MAR 16 20 DEBIT MEMO                              #10.00-         233.44        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              #.00          233.44        
 AUG 05 20 TRANSFER                 *40.00                         273.44        
 AUG 05 20 FROM ACC # 12345                                                     
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 05 SHARES                              40.00        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              #.00           40.00        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 07 PREMIUM SAVINGS                  1,720.64        
 JAN 31 20 INTEREST                  *2.19                       1,722.83        
 FEB 29 20 INTEREST                  *2.05                       1,724.88        
 MAR 31 20 INTEREST                  *2.20                       1,727.08        
 APR 30 20 INTEREST                  *2.13                       1,729.21        
 MAY 31 20 INTEREST                  *2.20                       1,731.41        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              #.00        1,731.41        
 JUN 30 20 INTEREST                  *2.14                       1,733.55        
 JUL 31 20 INTEREST                  *1.59                       1,735.14        
 AUG 31 20 INTEREST                  *1.55                       1,736.69        
 SEP 30 20 INTEREST                  *1.50                       1,738.19        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 16 EURO CASH SAVINGS                  100.07        
 JAN 31 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.08        
 FEB 29 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.09        
 MAR 31 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.10        
 APR 30 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.11        
 MAY 31 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.12        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              #.00          100.12        
 JUN 30 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.13        
 JUL 31 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.14        
 AUG 31 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.15        
 SEP 30 20 INTEREST                   *.01                         100.16        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 17 U.S. SAVINGS                          .00        
000000001                                                                      
                      ABC COMPANY                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
      JOHN SMITH                                                          
      1590 STEWART CRES                                                         
      NOWHERE AB                                                                 
      Z9T 6Y9                                                                   
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                  ACC: 000000001              PAGE:    2        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
 JUN 12 20 ACKNOWLEDGED                              #.00             .00        
000000053                                                                      
                      ABC COMPANY                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
      JACKIE SMITH                                                              
      MARTHA MAGEE                                                 
      28 HALL CRT                                                           
      NOWHERE AB                                                                 
      Z9T 6Y9                                                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                  ACC: 000000053              PAGE:    1        
                                                                                
   DATE    DESCRIPTION            DEPOSIT     WITHDRAWAL         BALANCE        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------        
                                                                                
 JAN 01 20 BALANCE FORWARD: 04 CHQ PLAN *63                      6,196.04        
 JAN 02 20 EFT WITHDRAWL                          #111.89-       6,084.15        
 JAN 02 20 ABC GAS                                                         
 JAN 04 20 CHEQUE           CK#     *66             #75.00-       6,009.15        
 JAN 07 20 EFT WITHDRAWL                           #62.32-       5,946.83        
 JAN 07 20 NOWHERE HYDRO                                                        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                 *29.49                       5,976.32        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   *.77                       5,977.09        
 JAN 22 20 DIVIDEND                   *.71                       5,977.80        
 JAN 31 20 INTEREST                   *.02                       5,977.82        
       
000000053 
"""
```

The Code:

```
ttp_template = """
<group name="DATA" method="table">
                                  ACC: {{Account_Number}}              PAGE:    {{ignore}}        
 <group name="each_account" method="table">
 {{Date_Month}} {{Date_Day}} {{Date_Year}} {{Description}}                   *{{Deposit}}                         {{Balance}}
 {{Date_Month}} {{Date_Day}} {{Date_Year}} {{Description}} {{Description2}}                   *{{Deposit}}                         {{Balance}}
 {{Date_Month}} {{Date_Day}} {{Date_Year}} {{Description}} {{Description2}}
 {{Date_Month}} {{Date_Day}} {{Date_Year}} {{Description}} {{Description2}}     *{{Deposit}}   #{{Withrawal}}   {{Balance}}
 </group>
 <group name="each_account" method="table">
 {{Date_Month}} {{Date_Day}} {{Date_Year}} {{Description}}                              #{{Withrawal}}                         {{Balance}}
 {{Date_Month}} {{Date_Day}} {{Date_Year}} {{Description}} {{Description2}}                              #{{Withrawal}}                         {{Balance}}
 </group>
</group>                     
"""

parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()

# print result in JSON format
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
#print(results)

with open("text_text_stack_data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(results)

#converting str to json. 
result = json.loads(results)
    
print(result)
```

The result is going to be in json format along with the account number of each line, see the sample, and please check text_text_stack_data.txt file to see in detail.

[image]

To resolve the 1st challenge, you will need to manipulate `ttp_template` of the code, add a few lines (like I have added) to capture missed data. With the current code, the lines which includes `BALANCE FORWARD:` will not be captured, and additonal line needs to be added under `ttp_template` to get this line as well.

Comment: Hi Baris - thanks for this - to answer your question I don't have the ability to get the file altered, unless I did it myself and some of the files have over 2 million rows of data so I wouldn't be able to easily update. However, I will try to work with what  you have an see if that gets me somewhere. I did notice looking at the file again, that the withdrawal transactions always seem to end with a "-" so perhaps that is something I can use to differentiate between deposit and withdrawal. Again thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Np. I did not get a structure that differentiates your `WITHDRAWAL` from your `DEPOSIT` from the shared data. As you know your data better than me, if `-` can help, or you can find a regex which hits only your `WITHDRAWAL` values, you can also use regex with ttp as well! See a sample: `{{ WITHDRAWAL| re("regex_value") }}`. `regex_value` is your pattern that should only match your `WITHDRAWAL` or `DEPOSIT` values. Thanks.